# how to solve this particular query?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
table1         table2 

col1 date     col1 date
a    d1       e     d4
b    d2       f     d5
c    d3       a     d6
```

I want a new table which have `4` entries `order by date` but `if any entries of column 1 replicate it remove this duplication also.` 
suppose if my date order is `d1>d6>d2>d3>d5>d4` then result should be:

```
col1 date
a     d1
b     d2
c     d3
e     d5
```

And I also want to know which data is coming from tabl1 or table2.

Comment: why `f` excluded? but `e` is not excluded?

Comment: @Michael well, if it's `top 4` then it's okay. Wait! Oh noes! It has to be `f` instead of `e` there!

Comment: Well it is e not f guys.

Comment: take another look at your table 2 - d4 is the date for e, d5 is the date for f - the final row in your required resultset ought to be `e     d4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
top 4 --you only need 4 of them?
col1, min(date) [date] from 
(
select col1, date from table1 
union 
select col1, date from table2
) t
group by col1
order by col1
```

Comment: and i also want to know from which table data is coming.Is it possible?

Comment: BTW we can also use limit for only 4 entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      col1,
      min( date ) date
   from 
      ( select col1, date
           from table1
        union all
        select col1, date
           from table2 )
   limit 4
   group by
      1
   order by
      2
```

And from the data sample, I think you want 5 entries.. you missed element "f" from your data.